# HTML5 canvas application (javascript) - how to detect a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, html, canvas

I've encountered a strange problem - application is rapidly slowing down as it runs. Only thing that springs to mind is a memory leak, but how to detect it in javascript? Are there any tools?
Anyway, here's the code:

```
function draw_ship(){
    //Body
    var sbpaint = ctx.createLinearGradient(shipx+20,shipy,shipx+20,shipy+15);//painting the ship
    sbpaint.addColorStop(0,'rgb(220,220,230)');
    sbpaint.addColorStop(1,'rgb(150,150,160)');
    ctx.fillStyle = sbpaint;
    ctx.moveTo(shipx,shipy);
    ctx.lineTo(shipx+40,shipy);
    ctx.lineTo(shipx+55,shipy+15);
    ctx.lineTo(shipx-15,shipy+15);

    ctx.fill();
    //Head
    var shpaint = ctx.createLinearGradient(shipx+20,shipy,shipx+20,shipy-20);
    shpaint.addColorStop(0,'rgb(200,200,210)');
    shpaint.addColorStop(1,'rgb(100,100,110)');
    ctx.fillStyle = shpaint;
    ctx.arc(shipx+20,shipy,20,Math.PI,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

As you see, it is very straightforward, and I'm really puzzled, where the leak could be.
Application itself is here:
[link](http://recon-by-fire.eu/html5.php), choose 'Scroller' from menu.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Memory leaks usually don't slow done ones applications. You'd have to have a *massiv* leak for that. For example if you use that much memory that it has to be paged.

Comment: Seems fine to me, what browser?

Comment: Tested in FF 3.6 and Chromium

Comment: It could be a problem somewhere else in the code, a slow recursion, failure to close your paths after loops, etc.  You could track that down using a profiler like the ones built into Safari or Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem proved to be as trivial as it was annoying - lack of **.beginPath()** method applied before drawing forms with lineTo. 
Thanks to everyone who commented.